# Is there a way to save all the history in Chrome in a reusable format?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I know the history is stored in a sqlite database, but I suppose there should be a ready to wear solution. Something as simple as a CSV or JSON file with dates and urls would be optimal.

Comment: What isn't reusable about sqlite?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sqlite is kinda reusable, but it only stores a few weeks of history. I want to log it persistently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Export your history as CSV with [SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)

> SQLite Database Browser is a freeware, public domain, open source visual tool used to create, design and edit database files compatible with SQLite. It is meant to be used for users and developers that want to create databases, edit and search data using a familiar spreadsheet-like interface, without the need to learn complicated SQL commands. Controls and wizards are available for users to:
>
> - Browse, edit, add and delete records
> - Search records
> - Import and export records as text
> - **Import and export tables from/to CSV files**
> - Import and export databases from/to SQL dump files
>     [...]

- SQLite Database Browser is portable. Has no command-line support to automate things
- On Chrome 30.0.1599.66 the history is saved at `...\profile\Profile 1\History`
- A view on on a history from within Chrome as example

  [image]
- Open database *history* » Click *Browse Data* » Select table *URL* » Go to *File » Export » Table as CSV file*

  [image]
- Your final CSV file will look similar to this

  ```
  "id","url","title","visit_count","typed_count","last_visit_time","hidden","favicon_id"
  "1","https://startpage.com/do/mypage.pl?prf=1fbfe14c3f3bebbd1a5fe1c0758af8dd","Startpage Search Engine","1","0","13024917645954087","0","0"
  "2","https://startpage.com/do/search","google.de - Startpage Web Search","1","0","13024917649780087","0","0"
  "3","https://startpage.com/do/search?","superuser.com - Startpage Web Search","1","0","13024917655295087","0","0"
  "4","http://superuser.com/","Super User","1","0","13024917657441087","0","0"
  ```
- The same could be done for your cookies, but not with your bookmarks file since it is encrypted

Comment: That only saves the current history. I want to save it continuously. One obvious thing is to just export the thing every other week, but that's what I want to avoid doing.

Comment: Well, then you should rephrase your question. You haven't mentioned this until now. Then, maybe others will come up with a better answer

Answer (score 0):

I've researched this a bit and what I have found is:

Your history is stored in the following location:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

You can add these files to other installations of Chrome to access them, but you cannot open them with other applications. If you sign into chrome with a Gmail account, your bookmarks will sync and stay with you. According to Google Groups, their beta Chrome editions are starting to sync history, but the live stable version does not at this time. So it will be something that can possibly happen in the future- but not now.